# How can I group and animate individual rows on this raphael canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

The following code creates a 10 x 15 grid of 40 pixel squares. I would like to be able to group the squares into rows for animating later. Specifically, I want to animate the rows dropping to the bottom and then apply animated matrix transforms to them. Eventually they will just replicate the same grid at a new location.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var squares = [];
    var paperHeight = 600;
    var paperWidth = 400;
    var squareSize = 40;

    var cols = paperWidth / squareSize;
    var rows = paperHeight / squareSize;

    var paper = Raphael($("#grid-test")[0],paperWidth,paperHeight);
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            // Begin loop for rows
            for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

              // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
              var x = i * squareSize;
              var y = j * squareSize;

              // For every column and row, a square is drawn at an (x,y) location 
              paper.rect(x,y,squareSize,squareSize); 
            }
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have difficulty animating individual rows if you don't store a reference to the squares which make up a row (presumably this is what the unused `squares[]` array is for...)

Each time you call `paper.rect` assign the result to an element in `squares[]`

You could then have an function which takes a given row of your array and applies Raphael's `.animate` to each square - giving the impression of the whole row being animated.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate

In response to your comment - you can add elements to a Raphael `set` and then animate the `set` -eg...

```
var squares = [];
var paperHeight = 600;
var paperWidth = 400;
var squareSize = 40;

var cols = paperWidth / squareSize;
var rows = paperHeight / squareSize;

var paper = Raphael($("#grid-test")[0],paperWidth,paperHeight);

var rowSets = [];

// *** GRID CONSTRUCTION CODE STARTS ***///
// I have swapped the usage of i and j within the loop so that cells
// in a row are drawn consecutively. 
// Previously, it was column cells which were drawn
// consecutively
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    //create a new set which will hold this row
    rowSets[i] = paper.set();
    squares[i] = [];

    // Begin loop for cells in row
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      var x = j * squareSize;
      var y = i * squareSize;

      // For every column and row, a square is drawn at an (x,y) location 
      var newRect = paper.rect(x,y,squareSize,squareSize); 
      // add the new cell to the row
      rowSets[i].push(newRect);
      squares[i][j] = newRect;
    }
}
// *** GRID CONSTRUCTION CODE ENDS ***

squares[5][5].attr({fill : '#f00'});            // colour an individual cell
rowSets[6].attr({fill : '#00f'});               // colour an entire row                 
rowSets[6].animate({y : 10 * squareSize},400);  // animate an enitre row
```

This means you could build a `set` of rows (and of columns) and animate them as individual units.

**UPDATE**

As a Raphael `set` is just a way of associating elements together to provide an easy way to apply operations en masse. It does *not* work in the same way as "Group" in Visio for example - ie They are still individual elements and will be animated independently.

Raphael will not find the centre of the `set` to do a rotation around. Each element of the set will be rotated around *its own* centre.

This problem can be solved by using a `path` to define an entire row at once as an [SVG path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands). However this means that rows are now "one entity" and you will have difficulty addressing one cell, or one column. However you could switch the indiviual cells for a "row path" before performing the transform. The user/player hopefully wouldn't notice.

You can replace the `// *** GRID CONSTRUCTION ***` code with the following code to build rows as paths... [(JSFiddle Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/QLfrY/)

```
//Build a row path - this path will be used as the basis of all the rows
var sPath = "lpw 0 l0 sq l-pw 0 l0 -sq " //outline of the whole row
for (var cell = 1; cell < cols; cell++){
    sPath += "msq 0 l0 sq Z ";           //insert an "upright" cell separator
};    
sPath = sPath.replace(/sq/g,squareSize).replace(/pw/g,paperWidth);

//we have no 'for' loop for columns now as we are creating entire row .paths
for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

    //we apply the 'M' (Move) offset here to the beginning of the path
    //This is simply to adjust the Y-offset of the start of the path
    //ie to put the the path in a new row position
    rowSets[j] = paper.path("M0 " + j * squareSize + sPath); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could raphael sets also be used to do this?

Comment: Thanks! If I do this - http://jsfiddle.net/codecowboy/XTsbW/8/ - then each square is transformed individually, not the whole row?

Comment: @codecowboy Yes, that's because a Raphael `set` is just an easy way of applying *the same* method to a group of elements. So each element will be transformed independently. This does not matter if you are only performing lateral shifting. For rotation / zooming etc you may need to apply a specific transform to each cell individually. Or you could achieve the effect I think you want with [`path`s](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path)

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the elements with a 2 dimensional array `[row][column]`. Then iterate over each column in a row to get the appropriate elements; then just animate them. Note that you need to swap `i`/`j` when bullding; currently you're building `[column][row]`.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ncHM/

```
var rowsArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    rowsArr[i] = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      var x = j * squareSize; // swap i/j
      var y = i * squareSize;

      // For every column and row, a square is drawn at an (x,y) location 
      rowsArr[i][j] = paper.rect(x,y,squareSize,squareSize);
      // draw and store directly, isn't that elegant? :)
    }
}

function animateRow(i) {
    var row = rowsArr[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) { // iterate elements in row
        row[j].animate({y: 400}, 2000);
    }
}

animateRow(2);
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to the example! (JsFiddle dying when I drag the Raph library in!)

Comment: @El Ronnoco: jsFiddle is indeed really slow at times :(

Comment: Thanks - this looks awesome. Any idea why this code loses 5 rows? There were 15 rows in my original grid and ideally this will be a 6 x 4 ratio grid.

Comment: Thanks - this looks awesome. Any idea why this code loses 5 rows?

Comment: cancel that - the cols and rows vars also needed swapping round for the nested loops